# Error in building qt from source on debian

Tags: qt, debian, build-error, qt6

I downloaded a Qt source from the [official site](https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/6.3/6.3.1/single/qt-everywhere-src-6.3.1.tar.xz).

I extracted it in home directory and try to build it using commands:

1. `./configure -developer-build`
2. `cmake --build .`

But I get this error:

> [ 48%] Running moc --collect-json for target tst_qmlsplitlib
> Error opening /home/yas/Qt-6.3.1/qtdeclarative/tests/auto/qml/qmlsplitlib/tst_qmlsplitlib_autogen/include/moc_tst_qmlsplitlib_library_tst_qmlsplitlib.cpp.json for reading
> gmake[2]: *** [qtdeclarative/tests/auto/qml/qmlsplitlib/CMakeFiles/tst_qmlsplitlib.dir/build.make:75: qtdeclarative/tests/auto/qml/qmlsplitlib/meta_types/qt6tst_qmlsplitlib_debug_metatypes.json.gen] Error 1
> gmake[2]: *** Deleting file 'qtdeclarative/tests/auto/qml/qmlsplitlib/meta_types/qt6tst_qmlsplitlib_debug_metatypes.json.gen'
> gmake[1](https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/6.3/6.3.1/single/qt-everywhere-src-6.3.1.tar.xz): *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:141639: qtdeclarative/tests/auto/qml/qmlsplitlib/CMakeFiles/tst_qmlsplitlib.dir/all] Error 2
> gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
> '''

I have MacBook Pro 2012 and with Debian 11.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Building Qt6 with make is not really supported.  There should be a CMake warning about that in the configure output.

Please install ninja and try to configure again.  The configure script will detect ninja's presence and use CMake's ninja generator.

You didn't share the CMake version you're using.  Please use a recent CMake, best something > 3.22.

If you don't plan to run the autotests, configure with `-nomake tests`.

Lastly, please report such build problems at https://bugreports.qt.io/ - that's a better place to reach us.